# How are ListView's ItemCollections related?

Tags: c#, wpf

If I create multiple `ListView`s with the same `ItemsSource` they become strangely linked.  In the following example, the two `ListView`s display a common list of strings.  The assertions show that the two `ItemCollection`s and `SortDescriptionCollection`s are distinct, but if I attempt to sort the `ListView`s differently, the second sort order is applied to both.

The two `ItemCollection`s must be related in order for the `Selector.IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem` property to have any effect, but I would like to be able to break this association so that I can do things like I've tried in this example.  Does anyone know how these collections are related, and how I can sever this relationship?

XAML:

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:llv="clr-namespace:LinkedListViews"
        x:Class="LinkedListViews.Window1"
        x:Name="Window"
        Title="Window1"
        Width="640" Height="480">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <ListView 
                x:Name="ListView1"
                ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=Window, Path=Data}" 
                Margin="75,8,0,8" Width="237" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        <ListView 
                x:Name="ListView2"
                ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=Window, Path=Data}" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,8,73,8" Width="243"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace LinkedListViews
{
    public partial class Window1
    {
        private List<string> _Data = new List<string>
        { 
            "Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma"
        };
        public List<string> Data
        {
            get { return _Data; }
        }

        public Window1()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            // Insert code required on object creation below this point.
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(ListView1.Items != ListView2.Items);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(ListView1.Items.SortDescriptions != ListView2.Items.SortDescriptions);
            this.ListView1.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription(null, ListSortDirection.Ascending));
            this.ListView2.Items.SortDescriptions.Clear();
            this.ListView2.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription(null, ListSortDirection.Descending));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Stopping ItemsControls from sharing filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066456/stopping-itemscontrols-from-sharing-filters)